# Add column based on unique ID in another column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to add the values in column "I" if the value in column "L" = "Closed" and the values in column "A" are the same.

[image]

For example: M2 would = "100", M3 would be blank (or `-`), M4 would also be blank (or `-`).

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share a dummy sheet with input and desired output so we can replicate your concern. Adding the code/formula that you have already worked on will also be great.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ST4nxdLxE-LwzjU-qVRZZUyFL_S43erywsoNbxy_xKg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing, can you please elaborate on the `"if the value in column "L" = "Closed" and the values in column "A" are the same."`. And can you provide more examples on the sheet.

Comment: I updated column L to what it would look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SUMIF` with `IF` formula in this case:

```
=IF(L2="Closed",SUMIF($A$2:$A$15,A2,$I$2:$I$15),"-")
```

RESULT:

[image]

In addition, I have modified your formula in `Col I` since it is returning `string/text` instead of `number`:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Realized PnL"; IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),, IF(ISNUMBER(F2:F*1), (D2:D*F2:F)-(D2:D*E2:E), IF(FIND("-",F2:F),"-","#VALUE")))})
```

I have removed the `text` formula, Alternatively, you can choose `number` format in the menu so that the two zeros will be retained.

[image]

REF: [SUMIF in Google Sheets with formula examples](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/sumif-google-sheets/)

*Note: I am not affiliated nor the owner of the site*

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,I2:I,L2:L,lambda(a,i,l,if(len(a),if(l="closed",sum(iferror(filter(--I:I,A:A=a))),"-"),)))
```

[image]